# Three.js Screen Tear

Tags: javascript, third-party-libraries

Using Three.js Revision 51 (Yes I know the latest is 84) I am getting a screen tear at random times on the load of my page. It seems like it's 50% whether it's a hard refresh or a fresh load of the page, it seems like it will have a 50% change to have this gaping black jagged shape in the middle of the object. But other times it seems to be perfectly OK.

Anyone have any ideas why it does this or what it's actually "called" so I can search better for it?

[image: Example of Problem]

Comment: Nevermind I figured out what it was, if anyone else sees this problem on their objects, it's caused by a bad Lens Flare texture... fml

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind I figured out what it was, if anyone else sees this problem on their objects, it's caused by a bad Lens Flare texture